# Reduce usage of map and filter combinations made on array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having array of objects as input I have to find and subtract the amount of `transactionAmount` field of an item that has the same `transactionReference` (as current item in a loop) and the `transactionType` equal to 13. In a final outcome I have to exclude the item with `transactionType` of 13 and do some custom actions on the rest of the items.

Given the array below:

```
[
    {
        transactionId: 45194,
        transactionDate: 1579858773136,
        transactionType: 13,
        transactionReference: 82941,
        transactionAmount: 1.21
    },
    {
        transactionId: 45193,
        transactionDate: 1579858773120,
        transactionType: 11,
        transactionReference: 82941,
        transactionAmount: 10
    },
    {
        transactionId: 45192,
        transactionDate: 1579858763947,
        transactionType: 1,
        transactionAmount: 10
    },
    {
        transactionId: 45191,
        transactionDate: 1579858759085,
        transactionType: 131,
        transactionAmount: 2000
    }
]
```

I came up with following function:

```
transactions => transactions
    .map(({
      transactionId,
      transactionDate,
      transactionType,
      transactionReference,
      transactionAmount
    }) => ({
      transactionId,
      transactionDate,
      transactionType,
      transactionReference,
      transactionAmount: transactionAmount - Number(transactions
        .filter(({
          transactionId: _transactionId,
          transactionReference: _transactionReference,
          transactionType
        }) => transactionType === 13 &&
        _transactionId !== transactionId &&
        transactionReference&&
        _transactionReference === transactionReference
        )
        .map(({ transactionAmount }) => transactionAmount))
    }))
    .filter(({ transactionType }) => transactionType !== 13)
    .map(({
      transactionId,
      transactionAmount,
      transactionDate,
      transactionType
    }) => ({
      id: transactionId,
      amount: Number(transactionAmount).toFixed(2),
      date: moment(transactionDate).format('H:mm'),
      type: transactionType
    }))
```

What I would like to do now is to reduce the numer of map/filter functions usage (while keeping the outcome) as I suspect the way I did it is not the most performant one.

Result:

```
[
    {
        id: 45193,
        amount: "8.79",
        date: 1579858773120,
        type: 11
    },
    {

        id: 45192,
        amount: "10.00",
        date: 1579858763947,
        type: 1

    },
    {
        id: 45191,
        amount: "2000.00",
        date: 1579858759085,
        type: 131
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you give an example output?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the steps taken to produce the output? Why do you subtract the first amount from the second amount - why not the other way around? Which date do you take? etc. If you could clarify those questions, I'll try to answer you :)

Comment: So the `transactionType` 13 is something like a factor I need to subtract from any other `transactionType` if they share the same `transactionReference` value . That part will never change. Date is not relevant rly, it's just being carried all the way down to result

Comment: I don't understand why the first one is subtracted from the second, why not the other way round? Where does that order come from?

Comment: It's just an instruction I need to follow. Now I don't understand how I can explain it in any other way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206575/discussion-between-user0101-and-kobe).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your array is sorted by transaction having type 13 first (*)

- Just build a map ref -> amount first
- Discard the transaction of type 13 from output
- For the other transactions, look up the amount to substract from the map (or substract 0)

```js
const transactions = [{"transactionId":45194,"transactionDate":1579858773136,"transactionType":13,"transactionReference":82941,"transactionAmount":1.21},{"transactionId":45193,"transactionDate":1579858773120,"transactionType":11,"transactionReference":82941,"transactionAmount":10},{"transactionId":45192,"transactionDate":1579858763947,"transactionType":1,"transactionAmount":10},{"transactionId":45191,"transactionDate":1579858759085,"transactionType":131,"transactionAmount":2000}]
const out = transactions.map(t => {
  // facultative, just preserve your eyes by making variable less verbose
  const ref = t.transactionReference
  return Object.assign({
    root: t,
    date: t.transactionDate,
    type: t.transactionType,
    id: t.transactionId,
    amount: t.transactionAmount
  }, ref ? { ref } : {})
})
.reduce((out, t) => {
  // build a map of refs
  if (t.type === 13) {
    out.refAmount[t.ref] = t.amount
    return out
  }

  const amount = t.amount - (out.refAmount[t.ref] || 0)
  out.without13.push({
    id: t.id,
    amount: amount,
    date: new Date(t.date).getTime(),
    type: t.type
  })
  return out
}, {refAmount: {}, without13: []}).without13
 
 console.log(out)
```

(*) If not sorted, sort them

```
transactions.sort((a, b) => -(a.transactionType === 13))
```

Comment: Thanks for asking on my behalf. I think your original description is pretty clear but likely someone else did not find it clear enough and wanted you to be even more verbose before some answer be proposed...